# How do we redirect to an external URL in warp?

Tags: rust, rust-warp

I want to redirect to an external URL like `https://www.google.com`, but [`warp::redirect`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.2.0/warp/redirect/index.html) only only takes a URI and not a URL.

Comment: URLs are a subset of URIs

Answer (score 1):

Copying the example from [`warp::redirect`'s documentation](https://docs.rs/warp/0.2.0/warp/redirect/index.html) and running it works fine:

```
use warp::{http::Uri, Filter}; // 0.2.0
use tokio; // 0.2.9, features = ["full"]

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let route = warp::any().map(|| warp::redirect(Uri::from_static("https://www.google.com")));

    warp::serve(route).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 8080)).await;
}
```